# Sorting the Timeline chart from POWER BI

Tags: powerbi, business-intelligence

i have a data where its Financial year is started from July and ends with June 
What I need is 
I want to arrange the Month in that order like

July -Aug------ Jan-Feb------ June

I'm tired of searching for a time series slicer and I don't know how to sort using queries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom sorting in PowerBI chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38185629/custom-sorting-in-powerbi-chart)

Comment: Create a column with the desired sorting order, and them sort your dates by them using "sort by another column" feature.

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated column using the following logic:

```
Sort Column =
SWITCH (
    'Table'[FinancialMonth],
    "July", 1,
    "August", 2,
    "September", 3,
    "October", 4,
    "November", 5,
    "December", 6,
    "January", 7,
    "February", 8,
    "March", 9,
    "April", 10,
    "May", 11,
    "June", 12
)
```

I have called your table `'Table'` and column `[FinancialMonth]`, this will need to be changed. Once you have created the new column, right click on the original `[FinancialMonth]`and choose the 'Sort By' option and select the new column.

Hope this helps!